# Excel VBA find address and assign to variable then reuse value

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to find if there's a given title on a cell, pass the address of that cell to a variable and use such location to adjust the size of the column. The reason I'm doing this is because I'm writing several functions which will shift the position of the columns. I'd appreciate it if someone could take a look and tell me what I'm doing wrong.

```
Option Explicit

Sub adjustColumns()

Dim PONumberCell As String
Dim PONumberAddress As Range
Dim TopLabelinColumn As Range

For Each TopLabelinColumn In Range("A1:Z1").Cells
    If TopLabelinColumn Like "PO_NUMBER" Then TopLabelinColumn.Value = "PO"
    PONumberCell = TopLabelinColumn.Address

    Set PONumberAddress = PONumberCell
    PONumberAddress.ColumnWidth = 70

Next TopLabelinColumn

End Sub
```

Comment: `Set PONumberAddress = PONumberCell` should probably be `Set PONumberAddress = TopLabelinColumn` (or, less efficiently, `Set PONumberAddress = Range(PONumberCell)`)  (And, unless you want to process **all** the cells that are `Like "PO_NUMBER"`, it would be a good idea to `Exit For` as soon as you have found the cell you are interested in.)

Comment: So modify the width of your column use `PONumberAddress.Columns.ColumnWidth = 70`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

edited after OP's further request:

you are confusing a Range object (such as `PONumberCell` is meant to be)  with a `String` variable one (like `PONumberAddress`), so

```
Set PONumberAddress = PONumberCell
```

doesn't work because you are trying to assign an `object` variable to a `String` one

but you can be more effective avoiding the loop and using the `Find()` method

```
Option Explicit

Sub adjustColumns()
    Dim PONumberAddress As String
    Dim PONumberCell As Range

    Set PONumberCell = Range("A1:Z1").Find(what:="PO_NUMBER", LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlPart, MatchCase:=False)
    If Not PONumberCell Is Nothing Then
        With PONumberCell
            .value = "PO"
            PONumberAddress = .Address
            .EntireColumn.ColumnWidth = 70
        End With
    Else
        Set PONumberCell = Range("A1:Z1").Find(what:="PO", LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False) '<--| if it didn't find "PO_NUMBER" then it seaches for a complete match of "PO"
        If Not PONumberCell Is Nothing Then PONumberCell.EntireColumn.ColumnWidth = 70
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks guys, your responses definitely cleared it for me. I have a ton of these headings and your help is a big push in the right direction. Also, do I need a second If statement to make sure I can reset the size to 70 even after the value has been set to "PO"?

Comment: You are welcome. I don't get your "Also" question: could you be more specific?

Comment: I'm really sorry for the late reply, I typed it a minute after I saw your response and for some reason, it was not posted. My question is if I run the code and "PO_NUMBER" is found, the column is renamed to "PO" and the size is set to 70, say I manually resize the column to 100 and now want to re-run the code to reset to 70, the With won't execute because the column is already "PO" and not "PO_NUMBER". Please let me know if that's clear. It's 4:15am where I am and it's getting hard to stay awake, so I apologize in advance if I don't reply to your next post until later.

Comment: Just to clarify, I know I could just search for "PO" instead of "PO_NUMBER" since the first part is the same, but the issue is that I have other columns where the titles are different from the values being assigned.

Comment: Big thanks user3598756, that really did the trick. I got long ways to go with this project, but people like you make it all worth it because I don't feel all alone in this journey and your help will be put to good use. Thanks again.

Comment: Hi user3598756 I was hoping you could take a look at another question I posted since no one has been able to guide me in the right direction and you were right on with this one. Here's the link to that other question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/41755602/7389937

Answer (score 1):

Following the comments above, there are a few erros in your code:

1. Setting the *PONumberAddress* Range, you need to use the syntax :  `Set PONumberAddress = Range(PONumberCell)` using the address string found in brackets.
2. To set the column width, use : `PONumberAddress.Columns.ColumnWidth = 70`.
3. According to your post, I think you want to do this only for columns where the header text is "PO_NUMBER", therefore you need all the code below inisde your `If` :  `If TopLabelinColumn.Value Like "PO_NUMBER" Then`.

**Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub adjustColumns()

Dim PONumberCell As String
Dim PONumberAddress As Range
Dim TopLabelinColumn As Range

For Each TopLabelinColumn In Range("A1:Z1").Cells
    If TopLabelinColumn.Value Like "PO_NUMBER" Then
        TopLabelinColumn.Value = "PO"
        PONumberCell = TopLabelinColumn.Address

        Set PONumberAddress = Range(PONumberCell)
        PONumberAddress.Columns.ColumnWidth = 70
    End If
Next TopLabelinColumn

End Sub
```

Comment: definitely, just debigged it a few times to make sure it works correctly .

Comment: I hadn't even noticed that single-line `If` - I just read the code as if it was a multi-line one!

Comment: @YowE3K what time is it your place ?

Comment: It's 7:25pm Sunday - I can't **really** blame it on being too tired