# VBA Excel remove Items unique to one sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I'm working on a long application and I hit a wall trying to find unique records between 2 sheets and removing the row from the first sheet if the record doesn't exist in the second sheet. Here's the code I have for this section of my program, I'm a bit confuse as to how to accomplish this and I'm hoping someone will be willing to take a look and give me some suggestions, thanks.
*Explanation: 
I'm looking for the unique records in column B and I'll be searching over 3000 cells in that column. If the records exist in sheet 1 but not in sheet 2 they should be deleted.

```
Option Explicit

Sub RemoveReversionItems()
Dim wbook As Workbook, Wsheet As Worksheet, wbName As String, wsName As String
Dim AlphaRange As Range, ReversionRange As Range
Dim AlphaArray
Dim ReversionArray
Dim x As Long
Dim AlphaSheetColumn As String: AlphaSheetColumn = "B" 'The column with the PO#
Dim ReversionSheetColumn As String: ReversionSheetColumn = "B" 'The column with the PO#


For Each wbook In Workbooks
If wbook.Name <> ActiveWorkbook.Name Then wbName = wbook.Name
Workbooks(wbName).Activate

'********************************
'    Look for Reversion Queue
'********************************

For Each Wsheet In wbook.Worksheets
    wsName = Wsheet.Name
    If Wsheet.Name Like "Revers*" Then
    MsgBox "This workbook is named " & wbName & " The Sheet is " & wsName
    'Get Reversion Range
    With Sheets(wsName)
        Set ReversionRange = .Range(.Range(ReversionSheetColumn & "2"), _
                .Range(ReversionSheetColumn & rows.Count).End(xlUp))
        ReversionArray = ReversionRange
    End With
    End If
Next Wsheet


'*****************************
'    Look for Alpha Queue
'*****************************

For Each Wsheet In wbook.Worksheets
    wsName = Wsheet.Name
    If Wsheet.Name Like "PO_LN*" Then
        'Load Alpha WorkSheet array
    With Sheets(wsName)
        Set AlphaRange = .Range(.Range(AlphaSheetColumn & "2"), _
                .Range(AlphaSheetColumn & rows.Count).End(xlUp))
        AlphaArray = AlphaRange
    End With

    MsgBox "This workbook is named " & wbName & " The Sheet is " & wsName
    End If
Next Wsheet

    If IsArray(ReversionArray) Then
        For x = UBound(ReversionArray) To 1 Step -1
            If AlphaArray <> ReversionArray(x, 2) Then
            ReversionRange.Cells(x).EntireRow.Interior.Color = 255   'Newtest

            End If
        Next
    Else
    End If
Next wbook


End Sub
```

Comment: A quick note: See how you linked any `Range()` to the worksheet you want that range from? Do the same with `Rows.Count`. Otherwise, it's just going to use the ActiveSheet (whatever that may be) to count the rows. That *may* be hindering some of the work.

Comment: Hi BruceWayne, thanks for the help. Could you elaborate a bit more as to how I should write it, meaning do I specify the variable range or the sheet in the parenthesis? That sort of thing. Thanks again for putting your time into this.

Comment: You, wisely, used `With Sheets(wsName)` and that allows you to use the `.` before `Range()`. That's equivalent to writing `Sheets(wsName).Range("A1")` ...you should also just add the `.` before `Rows.Count`, i.e. `Set ReversionRange = .Range(.Range(...),.Range(ReversionSheetColumn & .Rows.Count)...`  Does that make sense?  Also, you call `AlphaRange` but don't declare it first.  ...what should `AlphaRange` be in that first `For` loop?

Comment: Are you using Excel for Windows? Because there is a strategy for this that uses no looping!

Answer (score 0):

This function compares 2 data sheets with the same columns based on a primary key. It will highlight non-matched rows in orange and where the rows do match it will find any differences in the field values and highlight red and create a comment to show mismatched value (you can always removed this functionality)

Just pass in the 2 sheet names, the primary key col and whether data has col headers.

eg. strResult=CompareDataSheets("Sheet1","Sheet2",1,True)

```
Function CompareDataSheets(ByVal sht1 As String, ByVal sht2 As String, ByVal pkCol As Integer, ByVal hasHeaders As Boolean) As String

Dim ws1, ws2 As Worksheet
Dim x As Integer
Dim nmSht1, nmSht2, colDiffs, colName As String
Dim strIdentifier As String
Dim vmatch As Variant

Set ws1 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(sht1)
Set ws2 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(sht2)

On Error GoTo Err

If hasHeaders Then x = 2 Else x = 1

'Find Non Matches in sheet1
Do Until ws1.Cells(x, pkCol).Value = ""
    vmatch = Application.Match(ws1.Cells(x, pkCol).Value, ws2.Columns(pkCol), 0)
    If IsError(vmatch) Then
        ws1.Rows(x).Interior.Color = 49407
    Else
        'Find Matched PK Column diffs
        iCol = 1
        Do Until ws1.Cells(1, iCol).Value = ""

            If ws1.Cells(x, iCol).Value <> ws2.Cells(x, iCol).Value Then
                If hasHeaders Then
                    colName = ws1.Cells(1, iCol).Value
                Else
                    colName = iCol
                End If

                With ws1.Cells(x, iCol)
                .Interior.Color = 5263615
                .ClearComments
                .AddComment sht2 & " Value=" & ws2.Cells(x, iCol).Value
                End With

                If ws2.Cells(x, iCol).Value <> "" Then
                    With ws2.Cells(x, iCol)
                    .Interior.Color = 5263615
                    .ClearComments
                    .AddComment sht1 & " Value=" & ws1.Cells(x, iCol).Value
                    End With
                End If

            End If
            iCol = iCol + 1
        Loop
    End If
    x = x + 1

Loop

If Len(nmSht1) > 0 Then nmSht1 = Left(nmSht1, Len(nmSht1) - 1)

If hasHeaders Then x = 2 Else x = 1

'Find Non Matches in sheet2
Do Until ws2.Cells(x, pkCol).Value = ""
   vmatch = Application.Match(ws1.Cells(x, pkCol).Value, ws2.Columns(pkCol), 0)
    If IsError(vmatch) Then
       ws2.Rows(x).Interior.Color = 49407
    End If
     x = x + 1
Loop

If Len(nmSht2) > 0 Then nmSht2 = Left(nmSht2, Len(nmSht2) - 1)

CompareDataSheets = "Done!"

Exit Function
```

Err:
    CompareDataSheets = "Error: " & Err.Description

End Function

Comment: Thank you Aeneas, I'll  let you know when I integrate it in my module and test it.

Comment: Hi aeneas, I checked the function but is selecting every cell in the sheet which is not what I was looking for. Thanks for the help though.

Comment: Yes it will if the 2 sheets don't have exact same cell values. As I mentioned you can remove this part and just match on primary key columns. Just remove the loop below 'Find Matched PK Column diffs